# How to fix the Python code that deletes the last post in a Telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram

I'm trying to write a code in python that deletes the last post from my Telegram channel. Everything seems correct, but the code doesn't work....

```
import asyncio
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.error import TelegramError

bot_token = '123456fgdgz'
chat_id = '@username'  # Замените на ваш ID канала


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

    try:
        messages = await bot.get_chat(chat_id).fetch_all()

        if messages:
            message_to_delete = messages[-1]
            await message_to_delete.delete()
            print(f'Done: {message_to_delete.text}')
        else:
            print('Error')
    except TelegramError as e:
        print(f'Error2: {e}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When running this code, this error appears:

D:\pyMap\venv\Scripts\python.exe "D:\pyMap\main 5.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pyMap\main 5.py", line 29, in 
asyncio.run(main())
File "C:\Users\777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
return runner.run(main)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 664, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pyMap\main 5.py", line 15, in main
messages = await bot.get_chat(chat_id).fetch_all()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'fetch_all'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.get_chat' was never awaited

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a method that doesn't exist in telegram-bot. 'fetch_all()' should be replaced with 'get_chat_history()' in order to fetch the messages.
Another issue is 'await message_to_delete.delete()'. this should be replaced with 'bot.delete_message(chatid, messageid)'.
hopefully this helps